# Circle continuity principle proof

Tags: continuity, euclidean-geometry, circles

Circular continuity principle:

> If a circle C has one point inside and one point outside another
>   circle C' , then the two circles intersect in two distinct points.

I read this on Euclidean and non-Euclidean geometries(by Greenberg)
and I wanna prove it by Dedekind continuity axiom. I also have the segment-circle principle and Archimedes's axiom proven by Dedekind axiom.

Can someone please prove the circle continuity principle using what I have?

(Segment–circle continuity principle: If one endpoint of a segment is inside a circle and the
other endpoint is outside, then the segment intersects the circle at a point in between.

ARCHIMEDES' AXIOM : If CD is any segment, A any point, and r any
ray with vertex A, then for every point B  on r, there is a number n
such that when CD is laid off n times on r starting at A, a point E is
reached such that n · CD is congruent to AE and either B = E or B is between A
and E.)

Comment: You may want to format your question with MathJax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the answer page 262 of Franz Rothe book: http://math2.uncc.edu/~frothe/3181allneutral1_8.pdf
It is theorem 8.5.