# Using Dedekind axiom of continuity to proof the circular continuity principle

Tags: geometry, reference-request, euclidean-geometry

**Important note**: [Somehow similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1516131/circle-continuity-principle-proof) have been asked before and unfortunately the reference link for the answer of that post is dead. So please don't flag this question as repeated :)

I tried to explore

> T.Heath 1956 book series on ED geometry

to find out the answer, but my effort was helpless. Can somebody help me? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the link to the pdf you're looking for: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9uh0VymSVrpYWtHYXZ2d3Z2Rjg/view